TYPO3: gridelements image flexform, save images twice
TYPO3: 11.5.36
gridelelemts: 11.1.0
I have a flexform to save tree images. Here ist the flexform-code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<T3DataStructure>
  <meta>
    <langDisable>1</langDisable>
  </meta>
  <ROOT>
    <type>array</type>
    <el>
      <image>
        <TCEforms>
          <label>Bild</label>
          <description>Im Cropping-Modul 3:4 und den Bildausschnitt wählen</description>
          <config>
            <type>inline</type>
            <minitems>3</minitems>
            <maxitems>3</maxitems>
            <foreign_table>sys_file_reference</foreign_table>
            <foreign_table_field>tablenames</foreign_table_field>
            <foreign_label>uid_local</foreign_label>
            <foreign_sortby>sorting_foreign</foreign_sortby>
            <foreign_field>uid_foreign</foreign_field>
            <foreign_selector>uid_local</foreign_selector>
            <foreign_selector_fieldTcaOverride>
              <config>
                <appearance>
                  <elementBrowserType>file</elementBrowserType>
                  <elementBrowserAllowed>gif,jpg,jpeg,png,svg</elementBrowserAllowed>
                </appearance>
              </config>
            </foreign_selector_fieldTcaOverride>
            <foreign_types type="array">
              <numIndex index="0">
                <showitem>
                  --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,--palette--;;filePalette
                </showitem>
              </numIndex>
              <numIndex index="2">
                <showitem>
                  --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,--palette--;;filePalette
                </showitem>
              </numIndex>
            </foreign_types>
            <foreign_match_fields>
              <fieldname>image</fieldname> <!-- CAUTION!! Replace "fal" with the variable name of this field! -->
            </foreign_match_fields>
            <appearance type="array">
              <newRecordLinkAddTitle>1</newRecordLinkAddTitle>
              <headerThumbnail>
                <field>uid_local</field>
                <height>64</height>
                <width>64</width>
              </headerThumbnail>
              <enabledControls>
                <info>1</info>
                <new>1</new>
                <dragdrop>0</dragdrop>
                <sort>1</sort>
                <hide>1</hide>
                <delete>1</delete>
                <localize>1</localize>
              </enabledControls>
              <createNewRelationLinkTitle>
                LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference
              </createNewRelationLinkTitle>
            </appearance>
            <behaviour>
              <localizationMode>select</localizationMode>
              <localizeChildrenAtParentLocalization>1</localizeChildrenAtParentLocalization>
            </behaviour>
            <overrideChildTca>
              <columns type="array">
                <uid_local type="array">
                  <config type="array">
                    <appearance type="array">
                      <elementBrowserType>file</elementBrowserType>
                      <elementBrowserAllowed>jpg,png,svg,jpeg,gif</elementBrowserAllowed>
                    </appearance>
                  </config>
                </uid_local>
              </columns>
              <types type="array">
                <numIndex index="2">
                  <showitem>
                    --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,--palette--;;filePalette
                  </showitem>
                </numIndex>
              </types>
            </overrideChildTca>
          </config>
        </TCEforms>
      </image>
    </el>
  </ROOT>
</T3DataStructure>

In TYPO3 backend i get this:

When I first add the tree images and save the element, no image is saved. If you then add the tree images again and save, everything works fine and all images are useable in fluid.
